# Allow the user to use 'forward', 'back' or 'refresh' only they click buttons in a confirmation box

Tags: javascript, browser

[image]

This is Jira web. After I edited some information, I clicked forward/back in the browser. It will display a confirmation box. If a user only clicks the two buttons in the confirm box, only then allow the user to use 'forward', 'back' or 'refresh'.

How to make my web application run like this? Thanks.

Comment: With the `confirm` method? `const answer = confirm("would you like to remove?"); if (answer === true) { alert("answer is yes"); }`

Comment: I used this method before.It can give the confire window to customer,but user can still click browser forward/back button.I hope the operation like jira,display the browser confirm window,use only can click 'confirm' or 'cancel' button, do not allow user click other button like browser 'refresh','forward' or 'back' button

Comment: I'm stuggling to understand, if you want to block the navigation, that is not possible due to abused functionality of spams, the only way (and still, i'm not sure it would work) would be by creating an extension. HOWERVER I believe that box popups up when you try to leave the page, navigation is blocked after the `window.onbeforeunload` event, which is then captured and followed by a `confirm` box, but that's pretty much it when it comes to block user's navigation

Comment: by the way, i'd advise to use this functionality for good purposes, meaning loss of user input, otherwise your website will be flagged as spam

Comment: I am sorry that I do not descrip the question clearly.I update the question iamge.I hope operation like jira.when user edited some form then click the browser 'forward' or 'back' button , the browser will display the confirm window.after that user just only click the rwo buttons in the confirm window.do not allow user  click other button like browser 'forward','back' or 'refresh' button

Answer (score 1):

To prevent loss of user input use the `window.onbeforeunload` event that accepts a string as return value for its callback, with a `null` value as default to not prompt this confirmation

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
    return hasUnsavedValues ?
        "Unsaved data has been detected, do you really want to leave?" :
        null;
});
```